# Define transition property of clusters and cnclustered points in mapbox gl js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I'm using mapbox gl js to display markers on my map and the cluster function to cluster them as soon as the user zooms out. I render the markers like that:

```
// Create a layer for the clusters
map.addLayer({
    id: 'clusters',
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'markers',
    filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
    layout: {
        'icon-image': 'clusterBackgroundCircle', 
        'icon-size': 0.2, 
        'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
        'icon-anchor': 'center',
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
    },
    paint: {
        'text-color': 'rgba(21, 14, 86, 1)',
    },
})

// Create a layer for the individual markers
map.addLayer({
    id: 'unclustered-point',
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'markers',
    filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
    layout: {
        'icon-image': 'custom-marker-icon', 
        'icon-size': 0.35,
        'icon-anchor': 'bottom',
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
    },
})
```

In principal, that works fine. What I can't get to work is the fadein and out duration of the clusters and unclustered-points. I want them to be the same duration, which they currently aren't.

I've tried playing with the following, which is not working.

```
paint: {
    'icon-opacity-transition': {
        duration: 500,
        delay: 0
    },
```

How can I define duration for those clusters and unclustered points?